# Error 1: Invalid Function Call The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

good afternoon, I'm building a journey in jorney builder which there is a desistance split, which company the client goes to will follow a different flow

in one of these flows, if the customer is from company x he will receive an email.

I built the email and added the ampscript

```
%%[

var @passageiro, @nome, @cpf, @numeroBilhete, @dataViagem, @horarioViagem, @ogirem, @empresaCompra, @destino, @empresaOperadora, @plataforma, @poltrona, @tipoServico, @tempoViagem

set @passageiro = AttributeValue("Asset:Passageiro__c"),
   @nome = AttributeValue("Asset:Name"),
   @cpf = AttributeValue("Asset:CPF__c"),
   @numeroBilhete = AttributeValue("Asset:Numero_Bilhete__c"),
   @dataViagem =  AttributeValue("Asset:Data_Viagem__c"),
   @horarioViagem = AttributeValue("Asset:Horario_Viagem__c"),
   @origem = AttributeValue("Asset:Origem__c"),
   @empresaCompra = AttributeValue("Asset:Empresa_Compra__c"),
   @destino = AttributeValue("Asset:Destino__c"),
   @empresaOperadora = AttributeValue("Asset:Empresa_Operadora__c");
   @plataforma = AttributeValue("Asset:Plataforma_Embarque__c"),
   @poltrona = AttributeValue("Asset:Poltrona__c"),
   @tipoServico = AttributeValue("Asset:Tipo_Servico__c"),
   @tempoViagem = AttributeValue("Asset:Tempo_Viagem__c")

]%%
```

I'm just getting the following error:

```
Email Activity: BilheteEmitido -- The email specified for the job did not pass validation. EmailID: 37428 There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Error 1: Invalid Function Call The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. Function Call: v(origem) Attribute or Field Name: origem Invalid Content: v(origem) There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Error 2: Invalid Function Call The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. Function Call: v(empresaCompra) Attribute or Field Name: empresaCompra Invalid Content: v(empresaCompra) There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Error 1: Invalid Function Call The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. Function Call: v(origem) Attribute or Field Name: origem Invalid Content: v(origem) There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Error 2: Invalid Function Call The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. Function Call: v(empresaCompra) Attribute or Field Name: empresaCompra Invalid Content: v(empresaCompra)
```

Could you let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
<p style="margin: 0; margin-bottom: 16px;"><strong>Nome [passageiro]: %%=v(@passageiro)=%% -&gt; conferir</strong><br>Nome [AssetName]: %%=v(@nome)=%% -&gt; conferir<br>CPF: %%=v(@cpf)=%% -&gt; Atualize seu cadastro<br>Numero Bilhete: %%=v(@numeroBilhete)=%%</p>
                 <p style="margin: 0; margin-bottom: 16px;"><strong>Data Viagem:</strong> %%=v(@dataViagem)=%%, %%=v(@horarioViagem)=%%<br><strong>Origem:</strong> %%=v(origem)=%%<br><strong>Destino:</strong> %%=v(@destino)=%% Empresa Compra: %%=v(empresaCompra)=%%</p>
                 <p style="margin: 0; margin-bottom: 16px;">Empresa Operadora: %%=v(@empresaOperadora)=%%<br>Plataforma Embarque: %%=v(@plataforma)=%%<br>Poltrona: %%=v(@poltrona)=%%<br>Tipo Servico: %%=v(@tipoServico)=%%<br>Tempo Viagem: %%=v(@tipoServico)=%%<br><br></p>
```

Comment: Hey Felipe!

The issue is a missing @ sign for the script %%=v(origem)=%%.

It should be %%=v(@origem)=%%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error, where you forgot to include `@` in your variable reference. It should be `%%=v(@origem)=%%` and not `%%=v(origem)=%%`

Additionally, you have a typo where you declare it (in your first line of code). You reference `@ogirem` instead of `@origem`